# How to dynamically update the CSS Created icons via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a box using css3 and applying some gradient color scheme in it. What I am trying to achieve is I want to change the color and fill the empty space according to percentage-wise through JQuery but I am failing logically I have even googled but didn't find the appropriate results.

```css
section {
                /* background: #dce7eb; */
                margin-top: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .box {
                background: rgba(64,231,173,1);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64,231,173,1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68,237,168,1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77,248,157,1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82,255,151,1)));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
                background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1 );
                width: 66px;
                height: 80px;
                display: inline-block;
                margin:0 auto;

                position: relative;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
            }

            .box i {
                position:relative;
                width: 58px;
                height:70px;
                background:#fff;
                display:block;
                margin:5px auto;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            .box:hover span {
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
                transition: transform 250ms;
            }
```

```html
<section>
    <span class="box">
        <span></span>
        <i></i>
    </span>
</section>
```

Currently the box is at empty state i am assuming that the box is 0% of 100% what i want to do is i want to fill the white space dynamically through jquery also change the background of the box as the % increases. Like i jquery code encounters 50 as numeric ie 50% then the jquery should change the background color and fill the box 50%.

It very hard for me to implement it. Can anyone help me with this logic?

Comment: Where are you getting the number from (50 etc)?

Comment: From Database i am implementing it as a analytics

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do - This counts something as a number, and uses it to set a gradients percentage

```
var n = $( "div" ).length; //number
var nOver = n+1;
$('.box').css('background','-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(174,188,191,1) 0%,rgba(110,119,116,1) '+n+'%,rgba(10,14,10,1) '+nOver+'%,rgba(10,8,9,1) 100%)');
```

```js
var n = $( "i" ).length; //number
    var nOver = n+1;
    $('.box').css('background','-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(174,188,191,1) 0%,rgba(110,119,116,1) '+n+'%,rgba(10,14,10,1) '+nOver+'%,rgba(10,8,9,1) 100%)');
```

```css
section {
                /* background: #dce7eb; */
                margin-top: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .box {
                background: rgba(64,231,173,1);
                
                width: 66px;
                height: 80px;
 
                margin:0 auto;


            }

            .box i {
                position:relative;
                width: 58px;
                height:70px;
                
                display:block;
                margin:5px auto;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            .box:hover span {
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
                transition: transform 250ms;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>test gradient</p>

<section>
    <span class="box">
        <span></span>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i><i></i><i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
    </span>
</section>
```

Comment: What I am going to do is that initially, it will be empty as I send 10% i.e 10 from the database the current box should fill 10% of its capacity 100% is the capacity as it is full empty. You have provided the code I am not getting how to implement and where?

Comment: well you didn't specify that - you haven't shown what you get from the database etc - Then instead of a count with jquery, just count all rows from the database, and find what percentage your output contains, and set the percentage of your gradients start to that?